# Facebook Graph API Location Search Type

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi and thank you in advance,

I am currently trying to send a search request to Facebook Graph Api in PHP, and each time i send a request to the API it returns an empty array.

Sending my request to the Graph Api using the exemple on the developer page of facebook located [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/)

My parameters are the following.
Param
(
    [access_token] => "this is a valide access token that i removed to posted in the forum.",
    [type] => location,
    [center] => 45.33,36.210,
    [distance] => 2000
)

and the path of the request is the following : https://graph.facebook.com/search
with the Get method.

But my result is constantly the same, its an empty array.

Is this feature broken, not in service or am i sending the lat long in the wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook places restrictions on retrieving posts that specify locations. You can only return results for your query if:

- you or a friend authored the post
- you or a friend were tagged in the post.

See here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/